# Searching a Discord Message to set a filter

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to search a Discord message for a matched phrase and then use that phrase to set a filter for a filtered array - it works when I have only one phrase to search, but it won't work for multiple phrases or when no phrase is entered (if no phrase is matched I want it to have no filter) - any and all help appreciated!

```
module.exports = { 
    name: 'mission', 
    description: 'Randomly selects a mission', 

     execute(message, args) { 

       let missionArray = [
           {
               name: "Incisive Attack",
               size: "Combat Patrol",
               type: "Eternal War",
               source: "BRB",
               page: "286"
               
           },
           {
            name: "Outriders Attack",
            size: "Combat Patrol",
            type: "Eternal War",
            source: "BRB",
            page: "287"
            
        },
       //more missions here
            ];
            if (message.content.match('Combat Patrol')) {
                let filter = {size:"Combat Patrol"};
            } else if (message.content.match('Incursion')) {
                let filter = {size:"Incursion"};
            } else if (message.content.match('Strike Force')) {
                let filter = {size:"Strike Force"}
            } else if (message.content.match('Onslaught')) {
                let filter = {size:"Onslaught"};
                    
                let filteredMission = missionArray.filter(function(item) {
                for (var key in filter) {
                    if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filter[key])
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
                });
            
            let mission = filteredMission[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredMission.length)];
       

       return message.reply(`I have consulted the mission8Ball and you will play:\n**${mission.name}**\nMission Type: ${mission.type}\nBattle Size: ${mission.size}\nSource: ${mission.source}\nPage: ${mission.page}`); 
            }
}
};
```

I also want to set filters for source and type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want correctly, but you want to match multiple phrases related to mission parameters, then find missions that meet those parameters? Phrases like "Combat Patrol" (size) or "BRB" (source) or "Eternal War" (type)? What sort of messages do you want the users to send to invoke this? What are the minimum required parameters you want from your user when they send this command?

Comment: Hi Allister, My aim is that when a user enters !mission they will get a random mission from any available. When they enter !mission Combat Patrol, they will only be given a random mission from the array with the property size: "Combat Patrol", if they enter !mission Combat Patrol BRB, they will only be given missions from the array with the propoerties Size: "Combat Patrol" and source: "BRB", if they enter !mission Combat Patrol BRB GT2020, they will be given a random mission from the array with the properties size: "Combat Patrol" and the source: "BRB" or "GT2020", and so on

Comment: I'm working on an answer now that would get around the if/else branching, but you should know there's a big problem with your if/else tree: `let filter = `.... `let` variables are only active for the block they're created in. `filter` will be undefined by the time its used, after the branches. Speaking of which, you have a nesting error. Your `let filteredMission = ...` code is nested into the branch for `if message == "Onslaught"`. You should move it out, and set `let filter = ""` above the if else branches, then set filter like this: `filter = ""`. But I am working on an answer now.

Comment: This is great, moving the if else outside the filteredMission already works - however it then stores the filter  for future searches - is there a way to 'clear' the search after the message is sent? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, your scope should be getting reset each time you call. Doesn't matter, my answer is almost done.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've essentially rewritten your command and gone a little overboard but I believe it will make it easier for you to manage and add new missions.

Explanations will be in comments in the code. If you have comments I'll try to answer. The main thing to note is that the filter only assembles data to filter by if the value is in the possible options created in `option_values`. If someone wants to filter by a nonexistent feature, it won't be added to the filter, so filtering by `size = "AAAAAAAAAAAAA"` is the same as not filtering by size at all.

```js
let missionArray = [
           {
               name: "Incisive Attack",
               size: "Combat Patrol",
               type: "Eternal War",
               source: "BRB",
               page: "286"
               
           },
           {
            name: "Outriders Attack",
            size: "Combat Patrol",
            type: "Eternal War",
            source: "BRB",
            page: "287"
            },
                    {   //sorry made my own for testing
                        name: "Test",
                        size: "Incursion",
                        type: "Short war",
                        source: "BRB",
                        page: "300"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Test2",
                        size: "Incursion",
                        type: "other type",
                        source: "BRB",
                        page: "301"
                    }
];

let options = [ //what our users can enter in a message to set their filters
    "size:", "type:", "source:"
];
//I could've crunched these two into one dictionary but I feel like this way is easier to read and understand
let option_values = { //all the possible values for our filters they can set (ALL LOWERCASE!!!)
    size: [
        "combat Patrol", "incursion", "strike force", "onslaught"
    ],
    source: [
        "brb"
    ],
    type: [
        "eternal war", "other type"
    ], //continue on...
};

//enter array of filtered missions, get one random out
let chooseMission = function (missions) {   //courtesy of user rafaelcastrocouto
    let mission = missions[Math.floor(Math.random() * missions.length)];
    return mission;
}

const regex = new RegExp('"[^"]+"|[\\S]+', 'g'); //We need to parse arguments for filters that might contain multiple words, like "Eternal War". You don't need to understand this exactly. I got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671649/capture-strings-in-quotes-as-single-command-argument

module.exports = { 
    name: 'mission', 
    description: 'Randomly selects a mission', 
        execute(message, args) { 
            //this snippet parses our arguments to allow multi words like 'Eternal War'.
            args = [];
            message.content.match(regex).forEach(arg => {
                if (!arg) return;
                args.push(arg.replace(/"/g, ''));
            });

            let filter = {} //create a dictionary of information we'll filter by later
            for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { //loop over each argument
                let cmd = args[i];  //This entire block will define that the message !mission size: "Combat Patrol" type: "Eternal War"
                                    //will be parsed as cmd = "size:", param = "Combat Patrol" in one loop then cmd = "type:", param = "Eternal War" in the next
                if (options.includes(cmd)) {    //if our argument is one of our predefined options ("size:", "type:")
                    let param = args[i+1]; 
                    let key = cmd.slice(0, -1).toLowerCase(); //cut off the last character of our cmd (":"), make it lower for safety
                    if (option_values[key].includes(param.toLowerCase())) { //if the parameter we gave ("Incursion", etc) is an option we can use for our filter (size, etc)
                        filter[key] = param;    //use key as the key in our filter dictionary to match size to size.
                    } else {
                        message.reply(`Unknown parameter for ${key}: ${param}`)
                    }
                }
            }
            let filtered = missionArray.filter(item => { //item is a mission that contains properties like size, type...
                for (let key in filter) {   //our keys are already lowercase, try to keep them that way
                    if (item[key] === undefined || item[key].toLowerCase() != filter[key].toLowerCase())
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            });

            if (filtered.length == 0) { //if nothing passed the filter (note: this only counts if someone passed a valid option. If someone passes gibberish like "anafbia" for size, the filter wont try and search for matching sizes.
                filtered = missionArray; //select our pool of "filtered" missions to be the entire array
                message.reply("Can't find a mission matching your parameters.");
            }
            let mission = chooseMission(filtered);
            message.reply(`I have consulted the mission8Ball and you will play:\n**${mission.name}**\nMission Type: ${mission.type}\nBattle Size: ${mission.size}\nSource: ${mission.source}\nPage: ${mission.page}`);
    }
};
```

And here are the results of me testing the command:

```
//set: these inputs should come back with missions
input:
!mission type: "other type" size: "incursion"

output:
@Allister, I have consulted the mission8Ball and you will play:
Test2
Mission Type: other type
Battle Size: Incursion
Source: BRB
Page: 301

input:
!mission type size: incursion type: "other type"

output:
@Allister, I have consulted the mission8Ball and you will play:
Test2
Mission Type: other type
Battle Size: Incursion
Source: BRB
Page: 301

//set: this input should only filter by eternal war due to malformed parameters
input:
!mission type size: wrong thing type: "eternal war"

output:
@Allister, Unknown parameter for size: wrong
@Allister, I have consulted the mission8Ball and you will play:
Incisive Attack
Mission Type: Eternal War
Battle Size: Combat Patrol
Source: BRB
Page: 286


//set: this input provides a correct parameter but there are no missions that match it, so it returns random
input:
!mission size: "Strike Force"

output:
@Allister, Can't find a mission matching your parameters.
@Allister, I have consulted the mission8Ball and you will play:
Incisive Attack
Mission Type: Eternal War
Battle Size: Combat Patrol
Source: BRB
Page: 286

and of course, !mission alone will just return a random mission as well.
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! Thank you so much it works brilliantly. Now I'm going to go over everything you've done very slowly so I can understand it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution to your problem using a simple for loop.
I also moved the random selection into a function (chooseMission) to avoid duplicated code in the 'no content' scenario.

```js
module = {};
module.exports = {
  name: 'mission',
  description: 'Randomly selects a mission',

  execute(message, args) {

    let missionArray = [{
        name: "Incisive Attack",
        size: "Combat Patrol",
        type: "Eternal War",
        source: "BRB",
        page: "286"

      },
      {
        name: "Outriders Attack",
        size: "Combat Patrol",
        type: "Eternal War",
        source: "BRB",
        page: "287"

      },
      {
        name: "Incursion Attack",
        size: "Incursion",
        type: "Eternal War",
        source: "BRB",
        page: "287"

      }
    ];
    
    let filters = [
      'Combat Patrol',
      'Incursion',
      'Strike Force',
      'Onslaught'
    ];
    
    let chooseMission = function (missions) {
      let mission = missions[Math.floor(Math.random() * missions.length)];
      return message.reply(`I have consulted the mission8Ball and you will play:\n**${mission.name}**\nMission Type: ${mission.type}\nBattle Size: ${mission.size}\nSource: ${mission.source}\nPage: ${mission.page}`);
    }

    for (let f=0; f<filters.length; f++) {
      let filterStr = filters[f];
      
      if (!message.content) {
        return chooseMission(missionArray);
        
      } else if (message.content.match(filterStr)) {
        let filter = {
          size: filterStr
        };

        let filteredMission = missionArray.filter(function(item) {
          for (var key in filter) {
            if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filter[key])
              return false;
          }
          return true;
        });

        return chooseMission(filteredMission);
      }
    }
  }
};

module.exports.execute({
  content: '',
  reply: function (mission) {
    console.log(mission);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rafaelcastrocouto, this works well! (it may take me a while to completly understand it, I only started learning this a couple of days ago) There are a few follow up questions - how would I add a 'if no match, search entire array' rule, and how would I add a second filter, eg a filter by size and source? Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm working on an answer right now that will support multiple filters.

Comment: Great answer @Allister. You should try to understand this for loop before moving forward with your coding rik-powell.