# Only reading arguments inside strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, arguments, discord.js

Hey so I tried to do a message event that when you send a message to a specific channel it gets resent by the bot like this: -a(for making it anonymous)   
But im having problems since it would only register those if they are writedlikethis.
I would like to do so the args[1] and args[2] would only get read if they are inside strings like "", this is an example: -a "name of the thing" "description" 
This is my code:

```
   if(message.author.bot) return;
if (message.channel.id === '807760192774471680') {
   
 if (message.channel.id === '811730345912958997') {
    const args = message.content.trim().split(" ");
if (args[0].toLowerCase() === 'a') {
  const attachment = message.attachments.first(); 
const anonimo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setThumbnail(`https://seeklogo.com/images/M/Mercado_Libre-logo-990B0B4963-seeklogo.com.png?size=2048`)
.setTitle('Mercado Libre')
.addField(args[1], args[3])
.addField(`Precio: `, args[2] + `$`, false)
.setImage(attachment)
message.channel.send(anonimo)
 } 
   else if (!args[0]) {
     message.channel.send('no anonymous')
    } 
  } 
 })
```

Comment: You should use regular expressions.

Comment: What do you mean by regular expressions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture strings in quotes as single command argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671649/capture-strings-in-quotes-as-single-command-argument)

Comment: Please view the Duplicated Question, it has answers for regex and "normal" parsing. You are better off using the RegEx Version as its shorter most likely instead of the universal accepted answer.

Comment: so i got to this code but im unsure on where to add it, should it be in the same command.js or the message event? thanks
```const input = 'ban user "Look at what you have done!" 7d "This is another string" value';
const regex = new RegExp('"[^"]+"|[\\S]+', 'g');
const arguments = [];
input.match(regex).forEach(element => {
    if (!element) return;
    return arguments.push(element.replace(/"/g, ''));
});
console.log(arguments);


its the one on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671649/capture-strings-in-quotes-as-single-command-argument